# HTML conversion is not happening properly

Tags: java

I am getting text in html format in a string. My requirement is to display this properly on the screen.

I have a Java method that reads this text from database in a string variable. I want this to be properly converted and displayed as instead &gt , > has to be displayed etc.

Pasting the example string:

```
<p> <notes displayasdescending="yes" showtimezone="no"><note><date domain="SVR_DATETIME">20140415T190620</date><timezone>India Standard Time</timezone><author username="jus739it">Angela Merkel</author><content>&lt;p&gt; new note&lt;br /&gt; &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;</content></note><note><date domain="SVR_DATETIME">20140415T191138</date><timezone>India Standard Time</timezone><author username="jus739it">Angela Merkel</author><content>&lt;p&gt; &lt;notes displayasdescending=&quot;yes&quot; showtimezone=&quot;no&quot;&gt;&lt;note&gt;&lt;date domain=&quot;SVR_DATETIME&quot;&gt;20140415T190620&lt;/date&gt;&lt;timezone&gt;India Standard Time&lt;/timezone&gt;&lt;author username=&quot;jus739it&quot;&gt;Angela Merkel&lt;/author&gt;&lt;content&gt;&amp;lt;p&amp;gt; new note&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt; &amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&lt;/content&gt;&lt;/note&gt;&lt;/notes&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt; &lt;notes displayasdescending=&quot;yes&quot; showtimezone=&quot;no&quot;&gt;&lt;note&gt;&lt;content&gt; &lt;p&gt; new note&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt; new&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt; &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt; &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/content&gt; &lt;p&gt; &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/note&gt;&lt;/notes&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</content></note></notes></p> <p> <notes displayasdescending="yes" showtimezone="no"><note><content> <p> &nbsp;</p> <p> new note</p> <p> new note</p> <p> &nbsp;</p> <p> &nbsp;</p> </content></note></notes></p>
```

Comment: your source code is not clear :(

Comment: try with org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils

Comment: "please help its urgent" - remove this!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my above comment, use this package: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Dependency jar needed:

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str= "<content>&lt;p&gt; new note&lt;br /&gt; &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;</content>";

    String results = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(str);
   System.out.println(results);
}
}
```

Output:

```
<content><p> new note<br /> &nbsp;</p></content>
```